# SQL Unique User ID and workstation

Tags: sql, web-applications, logging

I have the following scenario:

A web application deployed over an NLB and a SQL Cluster.

In the database each table has a trigger to track activities done by users.currently the triggers are saving HostName (which is not useful in case of such web deployment).

Connection to the db is impersonated with the account "SA", Is there a possible way to obtain the 
connected user or the workstation sending the request inside SQL or I need to pass User Info into the db from withing the applications Code.

The DBMS is SQL and the web application is based on .NET framework

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass in the user id from the code unless you set up Kerberos pass through to use Windows Authentication. That is out of scope for this answer.

More importantly, why are you running a web app using "sa" on the SQL cluster. This is idiocy. Use a "least privilege" windows service account to run your IIS App Pool and use this to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: well yes i know that using "sa" is not the good practice but it was done on purpose since we have certain transactions over the db that requires higher privileges.

Comment: a feature to perform backups and restore to the database from the application like that available in SharePoint, generate reports about db activities

Comment: it not just a Read / Write application